# Can I attach metadata to images as they are dropped into folders? I'd like the folder name to be attached to the "Description" field

Tags: metadata

I'd like to use folder actions to attach the name of the folder images are dropped into in the Description field as Photoshop sees it.

Comment: Do you mean at you want the operating system file manager to do this? What operating system are you using? What would you expect to happen if you moved the file to a different folder, or to a different system?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its much more about how to use folder actions, a macOS specific concept, than about photography.

Comment: I think it's _topical_, in that organizing photographs and photographic metadata in general are both on topic — but I don't think we can answer without knowing more details

Comment: It is on topic as it applies to windows and linux as well, although there may be answers that suggest solutions which can be limited to a single OS. But that is then not the question's fault but the answer's.

Comment: The question specifically mentions folder actions, so it's the question, not the answers. that limit to a single OS.

Comment: Tweaking metadata through the action of storing/organizing a photo is a problem that the photographic community would run into. Because of that, I think it's a viable question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ExifTool. 
https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Somthing like 
exiftool *.jpg -description=%%d 
should do the trick. (Just guessing, never tried the same thing myself)

However, ExifFool does support so called pseudo tags for file and directory names for exactly this purpose (and the other way around, setting the filename based on other Metadata).

See 
http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/examples.html
and
https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html
for examples.